# Adding Windows XP on a macbook pro running MacOS and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, macos, macbook-pro, refit

My Macbook Pro already dual boots MacOSX or Ubuntu with ReFit. I would like to add Windows 7 in the mix. I can make enough space in the Mac partition to accomodate that, but just want to be sure the Windows installation is not going to wipe out anything and I will still be able to access both OS.

Anything else to watch out for is welcome.

(Sorry for not posting a question about an actual problem, but I figured that when I have a problem, it will just be too late).

Comment: Your title references XP and your question references 7.  Also, any update? :)

Comment: @Josh, that's pretty old.... I believe I followed the guide from the Ubuntu website, it has all the instructions there. Look for triple boot on Mac. Everything went fine (at the time, I installed Win 7, not sure why I put XP in the title)

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Yeah, I know it's an old question, cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recall seeing this on lifehacker.com a while back. I've only ever done the dual-boot with MacOS and Ubuntu, but this [guide](http://lifehacker.com/5531037/how-to-triple+boot-your-mac-with-windows-and-linux-no-boot-camp-required) might be of help if you haven't found it already.

Comment: There is also some information here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation . Thanks for the answer, I'll keep my fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1):

I triple booted on my Macbook pro with rEFIt between OSx Leopard, Ubuntu 8.04, and Windows XP.

The rEFIt page [says it does not support](http://refit.sourceforge.net/info/vista.html) Windows Vista because of firmware issues, and since Windows 7 is based off of Vista, I do not think you will have much luck with it.

Besides, to get my Mac to triple boot was an absolute pain. It required about 3 days of troubleshooting and using windows and Linux rescue disks to fix the master boot record and Grub. I do not recommend it. Do yourself a favor and just run virtual machines.